# Button wont become invisible after being clicked - Android

Tags: android, button, invisible

I have a button that is set to `VISIBLE` under certain circumstances, then once its clicked its suppose to make the button `INVISIBLE` again but for some reason its not working. Here is my code,

```
      if(variable == 2){

         testButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View view) {

                     testButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
                     test2Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
             });    
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried displaying a toast when the button is clicked, just to see if that block of code is even executing? I don't see it, but I'm assuming you've actually declared a View associated with that button via 'findViewById'

Comment: Yes I have tried a toast and the button Does indeed work. Also yes there is a findViewById

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:1**

Do this

```
public void onClick(View view) {

     view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
     findViewById(R.id.<your test2Buttons ID>).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Note:** If you do View.GONE it will leave all area acquired by it and the other control will capture this area

where is with `View.INVISIBLE` it will maintain its acquired area

Comment: replace test2Button with your test2Button button's id